# known hosts deleted / login fails

Tags: known-hosts

I deleted the known_host entries on a 1&1 Virtual Server. I once had changed the original root pwd for the server. With the new pwd as of right now, I can't login any more. The 1&1 support guy said the server is lost and i need to setup a new one. Now I have elaborated setup work on the server, which is not in the latest backup and want to avoid to start over the full cycle.

Question, is there another way to gain back control over my login ?

Regards, Frank

Answer (score 0):

Typical credential reset methods include:

- Single user mode via out of band access (virtual console or serial)
- Attach (a snapshot of) the disk to another instance

Either way, recover data and reset credentials.

Possibly if your hosting is unable to provide this kind of access, you may lose data.